# After appending element to page, going to another page, then back, the appended element is gone

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a bit long to explain, so I'll try to keep it short:

I'm submitting a form and returning a list of users, then emptying a  and repopulating it with the returned users. This works as expected until after I add a user and then browse to another page, then go back to the previous page, it's loading the list of users that was there before adding the new user. If I refresh, the user list is correctly displaying the list of users again.

Some pseudo code:

```
... function to add a user, then return success ...
$("ul#userTab").empty();
for(user in data['users']){
    $("ul#userTab").append("<li>"+user+"</li>");
}
```

It seems as though the browser is caching the first page load once I use the back button, but I don't really know. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm sending data to the server, saving it in the database, then returning the users from the database. I'm not just adding an arbitrary value to the page then reloading and wondering why it's not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is not going to maintain the DOM which you manipulate between page redirects. You have to use any history management plugin or using iframe to maintain the state of the page between page redirects.

Take a look at some of the links below, these might help you

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/

Answer (score 1):

A page is loaded with what the server sends to the browser, any changes made by javascript are done in the client browser only, and not on the server, so when the page is reloaded from the server it is the same as it was, what the server sends.

to make the change permanent, you will need to either send the change to the server using AJAX, or store it client side in session or cookies.

Comment: See my edit. I'm sending the data to the server, then returning data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

the obvious answer is that you're dynamically adding elements to the dom and not rewriting the page. If you want to preserve the results you should consider adding the results to a cookie and checking if the cookies exists on load, then display accordingly.

document.cookie ='users=html_results here; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/';